# Getting image/video from html into java servlet as new File()

Tags: javascript, java, html, xmlhttprequest

I want to get a file (image or video) from an

```
<input type='file' id='file_i'/>
// Not this <input type='submit'/>
```

Using an `XMLHttpRequest` like this

```
function img() {
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', document.getElementById("file_i").files[0]);
            var req;
            if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                req=new ActiveXObject();
            } else {
                req=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            req.open("post", "Image", true);
            req.send(fd);
        }
```

for example.
Then in the servlet doing this:

```
new FileInputStream(new File(request.getParameter("file")))
```

How can I retrieve that file?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Simulate file form submission with XMLHttpRequest Level 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963514/simulate-file-form-submission-with-xmlhttprequest-level-2)

Comment: Those two links should answer your question

Comment: If you answer my question giving me the javascript, html & java sample code for it, it would be greatly appreciated as it doesn't seem to be working for me

Comment: What Java techno are you using server-side? Plain servlets? JAX-RS? SpringMVC? Are you using an ORM? Hibernate? JPA? or JDBC straight to which DB? MySQL? PostgreSQL? Also can you use jQuery client-side?

Comment: I use plain servlets, MySQL connector to MySQL Database, and I can use jQuery

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed it. Here it is:

## JAVASCRIPT

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', document.getElementById("file_i").files[0]);
var req;
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    req=new ActiveXObject();
} else {
    req=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
req.open("post", "Image", true);
req.send(fd);
```

## JAVA

```
@MultipartConfig
public class addImage extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
        InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();
}
}
```

## XML

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Add Image</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.addImage</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Add Image</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Image</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss some points.

1. It seems in your JavaScript code, that you just create the request. But you didn't respond to results.

   ```
   req.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
   ```

   You should define reqListener like that:

   ```
   function reqListener () {
       // Here try to handle the response text, using "this.responseText"
       console.log(this.responseText);
   }
   ```

   See the full info here:
   [Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)
2. Also in your Java code, you just stated that you created a file stream.
   You should read from this input stream into the request's output stream. Also you should set the header `Content-Type: put_your_mime_type_here`, For example: `Content-Type: application/json`, if your file is a json file, `Content-Type: image/png`, if your file is a PNG image.

   See an example here: [Example for making a file download URL in Java](https://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-downloading-file-from-the-server-in-servlet)